# How to enable "Move a label ,Diagram or callout" option using qgspython

Tags: qgis

I wanted to enable one of the option in label toolbar i.e "Move a label,diagram, or callout" option

Can someone pls explain how to switch on this option with qgis python scripting

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Please be aware that, in general, questions asking for code are expected to include at least some code attempt by the asker. Personally, I feel that this particular question can be answered effectively without seeing a code attempt, which is why I have posted an answer. However, although this SE rule can be somewhat controversial and generates some diverging opinions, you should be aware that you may have coding questions closed/not answered in the future if they do not include a code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the Move Label action via the Python (really PyQt) API, you can use the following code snippet:

```py
# in a plugin use self.iface...
main_window = iface.mainWindow()
label_tool_bar = main_window.findChild(QToolBar, 'mLabelToolBar')
tool_buttons = label_tool_bar.findChildren(QToolButton)
for btn in tool_buttons:
    actions = btn.actions()
    if actions:
        for a in actions:
            if a.objectName() == 'mActionMoveLabel':
                if a.isEnabled():
                    a.trigger()
```

Note that for this to be effective, you must have a vector layer in the project with some active label or diagram settings, otherwise the action will not be enabled and the `trigger()` call will not be executed.